# gravando no firebase usando firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-functions

Boa tarde comunidade Developers.... 
dificuldade na gravação usando firebase...

o console do firebase cloud functions dá essa mensagem de erro:

```
decode64(userTo) ********@gmail.com
decode64(userFrom) YWRyaWVsQHVuaXBsYWNsYWdlcy5lZHUuYnI=
Uncaught exception
ReferenceError: ut is not defined
```

meu código está assim:

```
let ut = decode64(userTo)
let uf = encode64(userFrom)
console.log('decode64(userTo)', ut)
console.log('encode64(userFrom)', uf)


db.collection('users').doc(ut).collection('contacts').doc(uf).set({
lastMessage: messageDoc.content,
lastMessageTime: new Date()
}, {
    merge: true 
}).then(() => {
    console.log('[END]');
    resolve(true);
    return true;
}).catch(e => {
    throw new Error("User last message not saved.");
});
```

agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1):

ele passou a funcionar quando eu adicionei as seguites linhas >

```
            let ut = decode64(userTo)
            let uf = encode64(userFrom)
            console.log('decode64(userTo)', ut)
            console.log('encode64(userFrom)', uf)

            console.log('db.collection -> ', db.collection('users')) //essas 3 linhas
            console.log('db.collection.ut -> ', db.collection('users').doc(ut))
            console.log("db.collection('users').doc(ut).collection('contacts')",db.collection('users').doc(ut).collection('contacts'))

            db.collection('users').doc(ut).collection('contacts').doc(uf).set({
                lastMessage: messageDoc.content,
                lastMessageTime: new Date()
            }, {
```

Simplesmente passou a funcionar !!!